# Cannot assign to list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.x

I have been coding a game for a school assessment so excuse the basic code. My issue is that I am getting an error saying SyntaxError: can't assign to list comprehension on line 151 in main.py. For reference this is the function.

```
def winner(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5):
global players
string = 'total'
string2 = 'score'
[string+str(k) for k in range(0,players)] = abs(200 - [string2+str(p) for p in range(0,players)])
king = 100000
counter = 0
for h in range (0,players):
 if total[h] < king:
   king = total[h]
   counter = counter + 1
   print ('The winner is ' + player[counter] + ' with a score of ' + str(score[counter - 1]))
   print 'Congrats!'
   print 'Want to play again?'
```

The error comes with this line.

```
[string+str(k) for k in range(0,players)] = abs(200 - [string2+str(p) for p in range(0,players)])
```

Could someone please explain simply what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are trying to assign to a list comprehension. That is the source of your error.

Comment: Im not sure how to fix that? I cant find any sources which explain that

Comment: `[string+str(k) for k in range(0,players)]` cannot be on the left-hand side of `=`.

Comment: You have *another* error that will surface once you deal with that - you are trying to subtract the *result of a list comprehension*, which will always be a `list`, from `200`. This will throw a `TypeError` since subtraction isn't supported between `int` and `list` types

Comment: The solution is simple. Don't assign to a list comprehension. If you want more, then you are going to have to check out  [ask], and provide a [mcve], and specifically, explain what your code is *suppose to do*.

Comment: ... it looks like you're trying to assign to PHP-style variable variables. Don't do that, use a dict instead.

Comment: So really, you need to just explain what in the world you are trying to accomplish on the line that is throwing the error: `[string+str(k) for k in range(0,players)] = abs(200 - [string2+str(p) for p in range(0,players)])`. Both of those list comprehensions by themselves would seem to build lists of strings. What do you expect as the result of `200 - <some list of strings>`?? And furthermore, what do you expect the result of `<some_other_list_of_strings> = <that previous expression I just asked about>` to be?

Comment: @HughBothwell holy lambda calculus! You can do that sort of madness in PHP? I'd heard horror stories about that language before, I didn't know how much to believe until now...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes; `$a = "b";` then `$$a = 4;` sets `$b` to 4. Makes for *interesting* code.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like

```
def winner(scores):
    totals = [abs(200 - score) for score in scores]
    max_total = max(totals)
    max_index = totals.index(max_total)
    best_score = scores[max_index]
    best_player = max_index + 1
    print("The winner is player {} with a score of {}".format(best_player, best_score))
```

which you can then call like

```
>>> winner([-300, 100, 400, -700])
The winner is player 4 with a score of -700
```

Comment: That works to an extent. Only issue is that it displays that the best score is 200 and only shows player as winner even if there are other players. Sorry if it is an easy fix, I am pretty new to coding.